# PHP : Add <b> after links

Tags: php

I would like to add a `<b>` after each link (end of `href="aaaa">`) in a string whitch contain somme li a.

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a title="Voir tous les articles classés dans Actualités &ndash; Médias" href="http://www.aaa.fr/actualites-medias">Actualités &ndash; Médias <span class="nbr">0</span></a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a title="Voir tous les articles classés dans Alimentation &ndash; Gastronomie" href="http://www.aaa.fr/alimentation-gastronomie">Alimentation &ndash; Gastronomie <span class="nbr">0</span></a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a title="Voir tous les articles classés dans Animaux" href="http://www.aaa.fr/animaux">Animaux <span class="nbr">0</span></a></li>
```

How can I do ? With preg_replace ?

Thanks :)

Update -------------------

before :

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a title="Voir tous les articles classés dans Actualités &ndash; Médias" href="http://www.aaa.fr/actualites-medias">Actualités &ndash; Médias <span class="nbr">0</span></a></li>
```

after :

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a title="Voir tous les articles classés dans Actualités &ndash; Médias" href="http://www.aaa.fr/actualites-medias"><b>Actualités &ndash; Médias</b><span class="nbr">0</span></a></li>
```

For `</b>`, I've set `$variable = str_replace("<span class=\"nbr\">", "</b><span class=\"nbr\">", $variable);`

But for `<b>`, I don't know how to add after each end of `href="aaaa">`

Comment: The best way to do it is to add a `font-weight:bold` CSS rule to the links.

Comment: Where do you want the to go? Can please provide a "before" and "after" example?

Comment: <a style="font-weight:bold;" ...

Comment: `<b>` is presentational markup and should not be used. Either use `strong` or `em` if you want to emphasize this on the semantic level. If its just to make the links bold, use CSS as suggested above.

Answer (score 3):

Better say

```
font-weight:bold;
```

in your class="cat-item cat-item-1"

so no need to add other element